# Newbie having trouble redirecting to a url...here's my code. Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect based on a users input from another page. Or I want them to be able to view a specific file based on their input. First here is the code to direct them to a specific webpage based on their input.

```
<?php
    $user1=999;
    $user2=100;
    $user3=200;

$account=$_POST["account"];

if ($account==$user1)
   {
    header('Location: http://menu.html');
   }
elseif ($account==$user2)
   {
    header('Location: http://services.html');
   }
elseif ($account==$user3)
   {
        header('Location: http://about.html');
else
   {
    echo "this don't work";
   }
?>
```

edit - I've tried all the responses and comments in this thread and I am still having the same problem. The only thing I'm getting after I input the number is a blank page.

Comment: This code is fine.  What's not working?

Comment: It looks like you are missing host name in urls to me. Shouldn't that be - Location: http : //local.server/menu.html ?

Comment: You need the add the hostname, `Location: http://yourdomain.com/menu.html` or just the page `Location: menu.html`

Comment: always try to use `die()` or `exit()` after `header()`

Comment: Have you tried going to `http://about.html` in a web browser?

Comment: @AleksG What code are you looking at?

Comment: A basic understanding of HTTP would most likely avoided the need for this question.

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia Indeed, there is no warranty that the requesting client honors the location header and without exiting the code there is a possibility of disclosing unwanted information. Good security practice dictates that one should not ever ever trust the client.

Comment: If you're getting a blank page back, it most likely means that there's an error somewhere in your code.  Check the error log on your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: /menu.html');
exit;
```

Comment: As of HTTP/1.1 relative paths are not allowed. For valid HTTP/1.1 the location header should include the scheme, hostname and absolute path as per [RFC2616 section 14.30](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).